# Find cell starting by "abc" in row ; cut and past this cell in a column at the same row number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sheet with a lot of data, each row is a set of information, unfortunately, this information is randomly placed in the row; I would like to gather the addresses in the same column. The cells containing the address information start all by "adress".

My first idea was to cut past any cell starting by "adress" in a new column at the same row position and repeat it for the rest of the information so I get a new sheet with each column containing the same information for all the rows.

```
Sub toto()
    lastligne = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & ASR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolon = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & ASR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Column
    For NoLig = 2 To lastligne
        For NoCol = 1 To 30
            If Left(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NoLig, NoCol).Value, 1) = "d" Then 
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NoLig, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NoLig, NoCol).Value
            end If
        Next NoCol
    Next NoLig
End Sub
```

I have an object required error: `run time error '424'`

Comment: It would be helpful to know what line the error occurs on. Try changing `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NoLig, 7) = ...` to `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NoLig, 7).Value = ...`

Comment: You can remove `ASR.` from your first line.  You can also delete the second line, since it is not used and is not the correct method for finding the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Option Explicit`. This will force you to declare variables/Objects.
2. Define Objects and work with them with ease.

Is this what you are tying? (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub toto()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastligne As Long, lastcolon As Long
    Dim NoLig As Long, NoCol As Long

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col A
        lastligne = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Find last column in Row 1
        lastcolon = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For NoLig = 2 To lastligne
            For NoCol = 1 To lastcolon
                If Left(.Cells(NoLig, NoCol).Value, 1) = "d" Then
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NoLig, 7) = .Cells(NoLig, NoCol).Value
                End If
            Next NoCol
        Next NoLig
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: oh great , it works and does what I want , thanks a lot .